# How should date be formated for MySQL WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains a DATETIME column.  I wish to include a WHERE clause to limit records based on this column.  The format of the constraint is currently 08/23/2012.  If need be, I can convert the current format to whatever is needed using PHP.

Should I use PHP to convert the format before passing it to MySQL (and if so, what format should it be), or should I pass it this way, and use MySQL to convert it (and again, how?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert it in PHP:

`$date=date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("08/23/2012"))` represents the DATETIME format in MySQL

Check the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's official guidance but I find yyyy-mm-dd to be reliable when using code to format a date for a MySQL query.